# QODBCResult::exec: Unable to execute statement: "[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error

Tags: c++, sql-server, qt, t-sql, odbc

I get this error when I try to call stored procedure in QT using QODBC:

> QODBCResult::exec: Unable to execute statement: "[Microsoft][ODBC SQL
> Server Driver]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error

Amount of parameters is correct, syntax looks alright to me. The procedure executes fine in Management Studio. What might be the problem?

```
QSqlQuery query(db1);
query.exec("SELECT * from Teachers"); //test query
TableWidget *table = ui->tableWidget;
for (int i = 0; i < table->rowCount(); i++)
{    
    QComboBox *combo = static_cast<QComboBox*>(table->cellWidget(i,0));
    qDebug() << query.prepare("{CALL add_syllabus_line (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}");
    query.bindValue("teacher_name", teacherName);
    query.bindValue("subject_name", "????");
    query.bindValue("temporary_name", ratingName);
    query.bindValue("type_name", combo->currentText());
    query.bindValue("activity_name", table->item(i, 1)->text());
    query.bindValue("min_score", table->item(i, 2)->text().toInt());
    if (propertiesInstance.fixed) query.bindValue("max_score", 0);
    else query.bindValue("max_score", table->item(i, 3)->text().toInt());
    query.bindValue("max_score_exists", propertiesInstance.fixed);
    query.bindValue("evaluation_by_exam", propertiesInstance.exam);

    if (!query.exec())
    {
       qDebug() << query.lastError();
    }
}
```

The procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[add_syllabus_line] 

@teacher_name NVARCHAR(50),
@subject_name NVARCHAR(50),
@temporary_name NVARCHAR(50),
@type_name NVARCHAR(50),
@activity_name NVARCHAR(50),
@min_score int,
@max_score int,
@max_score_exists bit,
@evaluation_by_exam bit

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @teacher_id int;
DECLARE @subject_id int; 
DECLARE @type_id int; 

SELECT @teacher_id = Teacher_id FROM Teachers WHERE Teacher_name = @teacher_name;
SELECT @type_id = Activity_type_id FROM Activity_types WHERE Activity_type_name = @type_name;
SELECT @subject_id = subject_id FROM Subjects WHERE Subject_name = @subject_name;

INSERT INTO Syllabi (Teacher_id, 
                    Subject_id, 
                    Temporary_name,
                    Activity_type_id,
                    Activity_title,
                    Activity_min_score,
                    Activity_max_score,
                    Max_score_exists,
                    Evaluation_by_exam) VALUES (@teacher_id,
                                                @subject_id,
                                                @temporary_name,
                                                @type_id,
                                                @activity_name,
                                                @min_score,
                                                @max_score,
                                                @max_score_exists,
                                                @evaluation_by_exam);
END
```

`query.prepare` returns true.

I run a profiler trace and the query doesn't even shows there, only the test one.

> select 504,c.name,c.description,c.definition from
> master.dbo.syscharsets c where c.id = convert(tinyint,
> databasepropertyex ( db_name() , 'sqlcharset')) go
>
> exec sp_datatype_info 11 go
>
> SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
> go
>
> declare @p1 int
> set @p1=180150003
> declare @p3 int
> set @p3=8
> declare @p4 int
> set @p4=1
> declare @p5 int
> set @p5=3
> exec sp_cursoropen @p1
> output,N'SELECT * from Teachers',@p3 output,@p4 output,@p5 output
> select @p1, @p3, @p4, @p5
>
> exec sp_cursorclose 180150003 go

Comment: Run a profiler trace and see exactly what is coming across the wire.  Otherwise i have no clue where COUNT came from.

Comment: @Greg thank you for the suggestion, I used profiler, please check out the edits in details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be the syntax, I changed it to

```
query.prepare("{CALL add_syllabus_line (:teacher_name, :subject_name, 
    :temporary_name, :type_name, :activity_name, :min_score, :max_score, :max_score_exists, 
            :evaluation_by_exam)}");

QComboBox *combo = static_cast<QComboBox*>(table->cellWidget(i,0));
query.bindValue(":teacher_name", teacherName);
query.bindValue(":subject_name", "Физика");
query.bindValue(":temporary_name", ratingName);
query.bindValue(":type_name", combo->currentText());
query.bindValue(":activity_name", table->item(i, 1)->text());
query.bindValue(":min_score", table->item(i, 2)->text().toInt());
query.bindValue(":max_score", 0);
query.bindValue(":max_score_exists", propertiesInstance.fixed);
query.bindValue(":evaluation_by_exam", propertiesInstance.exam);

qDebug() << query.exec();
qDebug() << query.lastError();
```

and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Other than ensuring the exact syntax being passed to SQL Server using either a profiler trace or extended events, DBCC INPUTBUFFER etc, does the table being inserted have any trigger that might be interfering?

Comment: I used profiler as you guys suggested, it doesn't show the query at all (see edits). There are no triggers in the table.

Comment: What events did you add?  Ensure you added SQL Statement Started (in fact, add all the events), and add all the Errors events.  You should see the same error in the trace as you see in your app.

Comment: @Greg I'm using Express Profiler (I don't have the SQL Server Profiler in my edition), apparently it shows all the event by default cause there are no any setting. Is this what you mean?

Comment: i don't know anything about Express Profiler, but from what you're saying, it obviously isn't enough, you would need a SQL Server's profiler tool.  You can also try using XEvents mentioned above, but if you're not familiar with that, it will be tricky for you.

Comment: @Greg okay, I installed SQL Server Profiler, added all events from TSQL (including SQL Statement Started) and from Errors, still can't see neither my query nor the error from the app...